# Handle qooxdoo inline widget events in jQuery

Tags: widget, qooxdoo

I've embedded a qooxdoo widget (the table) within an existing web app using inline integration (http://qooxdoo.org/documentation/0.8/ui_inline).

Is it possible to raise an event in the widget that can be handled externally within the main web app? Specifically I want to raise a "row selected" event when the user selects an item in the table.

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

afaik the table selection model has the event "changeSelection".

```
tableInstance.getSelectionModel().addListener("changeSelection", yourListener, yourContext);
```

With this event you can get the necessary infos within your listener method and fire an event to a DOM element which any JS library can use to listen to.

```
qx.event.Registration.fireEvent(document.body, "rowSelected", qx.event.type.Event);
```

You can fire the event at every DOM element you like to. In your case you can use jQuery to listen to the event and get the infos.

Hope that helps you further.

Regards,
  Alex